# error C2380: type(s) preceding 'Form1' OpenCV C Header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, managed

Can anyone help me solve this?

```
error C2380: type(s) preceding 'Form1' (constructor wit`h return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)`
```

I try to make a program using windows form in Visual c++ 2008. But I got that error above.

below is my header file code part >> form1.h:

```
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
```

Actually i have browsed about this error, but stil because my stupidity I still cant figure it out..

Comment: It probably means that `Form1` is a constructor, so it should have no return type. And that `^` stuff is not C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's managed C++ (.NET) - added tags

Answer (score 0):

Constructors should not be declared as returning anything.  You just need to omit System::Void:

```
  private: Form1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // implement your constructor here
    }
```